# Automatically Show ShapeSheet of Current Shape

Tags: vba, optimization, visio, shapesheet

I do a lot of Visio ShapeSheet editing and it would save me a tremendous amount of time to automatically switch to the current shape's sheet when I select a new shape. Let's assume I only have 1 ShapeSheet open, only select 1 Shape, and have all the windows docked on the Visio app (I don't have RegEdit powers to change this).

So far, I've got the following VBA code in `ThisDocument`:

```
Private WithEvents vsoWin as Visio.Window

Private Sub ThisDocument_RunModeEntered(ByRef doc as IVDocument)
    'Just assume this is the correct window
    Set vsoWin = ActiveWindow
End Sub

Private Sub vsoWin_SelectionChanged(ByRef win as IVWindow)
    'If nothing is selected, leave
    If vsoWin.Selection.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub

    'Look for a ShapeSheet (Window.SubType = 3)
    For each oWin in Application.Windows
        If oWin.Subtype = 3 Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False    'Pause screen to prevent jitter
            oWin.Close                            'Delete old ShapeSheet
            vsoWin.Selection(1).OpenSheetWindow   'Make new ShapeSheet
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True     'Update visuals
            Exit For                              'Stop looking for ShapeSheets
        End If
    Next
Exit Sub
```

*(The above code is written from memory since I don't have access to Visio at the moment. Please forgive any minor errors)*

This code works, but I'm hoping for a less jittery result. `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` doesn't seem to do anything in this case: I still briefly witness the old ShapeSheet closing, the drawing window resizing, then the new ShapeSheet opening. Swapping the order (open new window > close old window) is a little less chaotic, but not great. Using `Application.Minimize` to hide the swap instead is slightly better on the eyes, but still not a smooth transition.

My question: **Is there a smoother way to display the active shape's ShapeSheet?**

Comment: Please try [ShapeSheet Watch tool](https://unmanagedvisio.com/shapesheet-watch-multiselect/)

Comment: @Surrogate This looks wonderful! Unfortunately, my org doesn't allow for any add-ins (despite unrestricted access to VBA).

Answer (score 2):

This code works at my side! I just add variable which related with Visio Application - vsoApp.

```
Private WithEvents vsoWin As Visio.Window
Private WithEvents vsoApp As Visio.Application

Sub st()
Set vsoWin = ActiveWindow ' initialize Window variable
Set vsoApp = Application ' initialize Application variable
End Sub

Private Sub ThisDocument_RunModeEntered(ByRef doc As IVDocument)
    'Just assume this is the correct window
    Set vsoWin = ActiveWindow
End Sub

Private Sub vsoApp_SelectionChanged(ByVal Window As IVWindow)
    'If nothing is selected, leave
    
    If vsoWin.Selection.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub

    'Look for a ShapeSheet (Window.SubType = 3)
    For Each oWin In Application.Windows
        If oWin.SubType = 3 Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False    'Pause screen to prevent jitter
            oWin.Close                            'Delete old ShapeSheet
            vsoWin.Selection(1).OpenSheetWindow   'Make new ShapeSheet
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True     'Update visuals
            Exit For                              'Stop looking for ShapeSheets
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

My workaround:

1. Press **Alt**+**F8** keys and run **St sub-routine**.
2. Open ShapeSheet window for selected shape.
3. Select another shapes and so on...
   [image: Imgur]

---

**Update** with your code i get error like this.
[image: Compile error]

Comment: Does changing it to an App event instead of a Window event make the process visually smoother? The code I posted works, it just isn't visually pleasant to watch in action. Sorry, won't be able to run this myself for a few days.

Comment: At my side i get error in line `Private Sub vsoWin_SelectionChanged(ByRef win as IVWindow)`. Add GIF with results, where my code works

Comment: Oh how weird. I'm using Visio 2016, and per the documentation a Visio object does have a [SelectionChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.window.selectionchanged). I use it all the time.

Comment: I use Visio 2019, and also use this event. At my side error fired as argument of this event, i.e. _By Ref win as IVWindow_.